# Передавать и принимать поток. Socket

Tags: c#, сокет, xaml, uwp, потоки-данных

Записываю картинку с камеры в поток:

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(encodingProfile,stream);
```

Задача: как-то разбить этот на байты и передать его по сокету, а на приеме снова создать поток? Получается своего рода трансляция.

Поток необходимо шифровать и дешифровать с помощью aes. Метод шифрования реализован, принимает массив байт. Как передать туда поток?

Comment: Разбивать на байты не нужно. Просто пишите в сокет. Протокол TCP сам позаботится о фрагментации отсылаемых данных. И точно это будет не так, как Вы задумаете. Ваша задача будет собрать эти кусочки на другой стороне.

Comment: У меня будет UDP, а не TCP. И как записать поток в сокет? Я только знаю про SocketAsyncEventArgs, где есть параметр буфер, а потом этот объект передается в сокет. В чем проблема сбора на той стороне?

Comment: UDP не работает с потоком, он работает с дейтаграммами. Поскольку порядок прихода дейтаграмм не гарантирован, вы не можете так просто слать данные, вам нужны какие-нибудь маркеры того, что эти данные собой представляют.

Comment: Хорошо, как сделать дейтаграмму?

Comment: @SanychGoilo, зачем все усложнять? Зачем UDP? Используйте TCP клиент или сокет! Так же советую свойство NoDelay клиента или сокета - задать в true.

Comment: @SanychGoilo, читайте это или ищите материал в гугле: http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level4/4_1.php

Comment: Я использую сервер для только для соединения клиента с клиентом, что не возможно на tcp. Ссылка хорошо рассказывает про сами протоколы, но не как мне передать поток.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой код получается:

```
private async Task<IDisposable> SendStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile encodingProfile, MediaCapture mediaCapture)
{
    var socket = new DatagramSocket();

    var outputStream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(new HostName("example.com"), "12345");

    var writeOnlyStream = new WriteOnlyStreamStream(outputStream);

    await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(encodingProfile, writeOnlyStream);

    return new CompositeDisposable {writeOnlyStream, outputStream, socket};
}

private sealed class WriteOnlyStreamStream : IRandomAccessStream
{
    readonly IOutputStream _outputStream;

    public WriteOnlyStreamStream(IOutputStream outputStream)
    {
        _outputStream = outputStream;
    }

    public IInputStream GetInputStreamAt(ulong position)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(); //or we can return empty stream
    }

    public IOutputStream GetOutputStreamAt(ulong position)
    {
        return _outputStream;
    }

    public ulong Size
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }

    public bool CanRead => false;

    public bool CanWrite => true;

    public IRandomAccessStream CloneStream()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public ulong Position => 0;

    public void Seek(ulong position)
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._outputStream.Dispose();
    }

    public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, uint> ReadAsync(IBuffer buffer, uint count, InputStreamOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<uint, uint> WriteAsync(IBuffer buffer)
    {
        return _outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<bool> FlushAsync()
    {
        return _outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Что здесь происходит:

1. Создали Udp сокет (в нем пакеты будут теряться, биться, никакой целостности)
2. Создали спец-класс обертку, чтобы пропихнуть IOutputStream внутрь MediaCapture. Здесь есть варианты, можно вместо исключений возвращать пустой IInputStream
3. Создали IDisposable, который надо будет закрыть после всех операций (используем Reactive Extensions).

Как правильнее посоветовали в вопросах, здесь лучше использовать TCP сокеты. Для клиентской части будет всё 1-в-1, только классы немного поменяются. Для серверной части надо использовать класс StreamSocketListener (он есть в uwp), с которого уже слушать какой-нибудь порт.

Comment: Про udp часто мелькает фраза "Будут биться пакеты" - что это значит? Например, я передаю видео, это значит что клиент может увидеть плохую картинку?

Comment: Всё зависит от кодека. Может просто остановиться проигрывания, может потеряться кадр, погут прийти цифровые помехи (когда картинка как бы "рассыпается"). Например, есть разные виды кадров (см. википедию). Есть т.н. "опорные кадры", которые кодируются как картинка. Если и другие, которые задаются в стиле "во-он тот опорный, но надо поменять вот эти пикселы, а эти фрагменты подвинуть вверх на 35 пикселов, и т.д.". Тут уже сразу ясно, что битый опорный кадр сделает проблему для всей последовательности. При передачи по TCP будет пауза до тех пор, пока по каналу данные таки не передадутся.

Comment: И как часто случается эта потеря пакетов?

Comment: Это надо уже детальнее изучать. Если работать в локальной сети на свободнои канале (т.е. без торрентов и пр.), то почти никогда. Ограничение скорости у провайдера - это выкидывание пакетов (см. алгоритм текущего ведра - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0) . Если идет работа по мобильной сети, то процент может быть большим, особенно, если идет переподключение между протоколами.

Comment: Я в замешательстве. Что Вы хотите сказать под большим процентом? Если провайдеры выкидывают пакеты и много теряется при передаче через мобильную сеть, то как вообще живет UDP?

Comment: А он почти не используется для простых программ. Видео может теряться (это нормально, клиенты умеют правильно это обрабатывать), в играх на пару секунд тоже может быть затуп (и то, всё это относится только к шутерам)

Comment: На счет кода, отправить это хорошо, а как потом принять?

Comment: Как мне зашифровать поток с помощью aes? Метод шифрования реализован, как передать?